# LibGDX - Dialog - how to remove the titlebar?

Tags: java, libgdx

I just started using LibGDX. I'm trying to create a notification system like on a video below. I've extended the Dialog class (cause Label can't have it's own background).

I learned some 'MoveToActions' and the dialogs slides. I need to remove the titlebar somehow, but 'getTitleLabel()' and 'getTitleTable()' don't want to work.

Any ideas? :) Thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVxfyVUAqCQ

[image]

Comment: It cannot be removed, but you can set the title to `""`, and use a background that doesn't have the title bar area. Someone should do a pull request to make the title bar optional. Hmm.

Comment: Isn't there any option to setting it's height to 0 or smth? This is so stupid O.o

Answer (score 1):

If you would prefer to use Label instead of Dialog, Label actually can have its own background. LabelStyle has a parameter for setting a Drawable as the background and when creating a new Label use this constructor:

```
Label(java.lang.CharSequence text, Label.LabelStyle style)
```

Here is the API for LabelStyle:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.LabelStyle.html